# Parsing Token Program Transactions

Tags: anchor, spl-token, spl, spl-associated-token-account, idl

I'm currently working on monitoring the Solana Token Program with the address `TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA`.

My goal is to filter out specific events, namely Token Mints, Token Burns, New Pools (initializeAccount), and Liquidity Addition/Removal.

I'm exploring the optimal approach for reading the instructions and extracting information invovled such as token mints and the associated amounts.

Is going the Anchor route by fetching the IDL of the program and parseing a possibility?

I'm curious about the methods used by projects like Helius/Shyft to effectively parse this data.

Could anyone provide insights or guidance on the most efficient and accurate approach to achieving this task?

TIA

Answer (score 0):

Instructions to the SPL Token program are actually parsed for you by the validator if you request `jsonParsed` encoding when fetching transactions.

For example, if you use `getTransaction` https://solana.com/docs/rpc/http/gettransaction with `"encoding": "jsonParsed"`, any instruction to the SPL Token program will be parsed for you.

Here's an example:

```
            {
                "instructionType": "transfer",
                "info": {
                    "source": "<SOURCE_ACCOUNT_PUBKEY_AS_STRING>",
                    "destination": "<DESTINATION_ACCOUNT_PUBKEY_AS_STRING>",
                    "authority": "<OWNER_ACCOUNT_PUBKEY_AS_STRING>",
                    "amount": "42",
                }
            }
```

Here's the file that does the parsing: https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/blob/master/transaction-status/src/parse_token.rs